# Find the factorisation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the prime factorisation of all numbers that are of the form $4k+1$ such that $k \neq 4ab+a+b$ for some positive integer values of $a,b$.

I failed to find it the other way round as well, i.e., all numbers of the form $4k+1$ where $k=4ab+a+b$.

Both way, it seems to be a nice question but I can't find out how to get the factorisation. Any hint or solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: HINT: $4k+1=16ab+4a+4b+1=(4a+1)(4b+1)$. So, you are looking for numbers congruent to $1\mod 4$ that aren't the product of numbers congruent to $1\mod 4$ and greater than 4.

Comment: I could figure that out but that not how to get the standard prime factorisation from there.

Comment: Basically, you should realize that the prime factorization is all numbers of the form $4k-1$, where $k>0$. But, it must be an even number of such terms in the prime factorization.